# Ordenar pandas dataframe por indice

Tags: python, pandas, indices

Un saludo a todos

Tengo el siguiente pandas dataframe:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría ordenarla de mayor a menor basado en el indice no importa que este se repita, lo que digo quedaría así:

El valor máximo corresponde al Cmpd6 = 0.79, le sigue Cmpd4 = 0.69 ... en algún punto Cmpd6 = 0.56 lo que  quisiera que deje la lista así:

```
Cmpd6 = 0.79
Cmpd4 = 0.69
Cmpdx = x
Cmpd6 = 0.56
```

Esto con cada valor de la matriz, no importando las veces que los indices se repitan, estuve intentando con `.sort_index(axis=1)` pero no me produce nada de esto, asimismo intente con .ravel() pero no me da los indices. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

De antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres obtener todos los valores (celdas) ordenadas y el índice al que pertenecen como creo, posiblemente NumPy ofrezca una buena solución.

Primero vamos a reproducir un ejemplo similar al que muestras:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = io.StringIO("""\
idx   Cmpd1 Cmpd2 Cmpd3 Cmpd4 Cmpd5 Cmpd6
Cmpd1     1                              
Cmpd2   0.4     1                        
Cmpd3   0.6   0.3     1                  
Cmpd4  0.46  0.69  0.32     1            
Cmpd5  0.57  0.44  0.41  0.51     1      
Cmpd6  0.41  0.79  0.33  0.56  0.43     1
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\s+", engine="python", index_col="idx")
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>        Cmpd1  Cmpd2  Cmpd3  Cmpd4  Cmpd5  Cmpd6
> idx                                            
> Cmpd1   1.00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
> Cmpd2   0.40   1.00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
> Cmpd3   0.60   0.30   1.00    NaN    NaN    NaN
> Cmpd4   0.46   0.69   0.32   1.00    NaN    NaN
> Cmpd5   0.57   0.44   0.41   0.51   1.00    NaN
> Cmpd6   0.41   0.79   0.33   0.56   0.43    1.0
> ```

Ahora primero vamos a descartar todos los datos que están por encima de la diagonal principal, incluida ésta. Para ello `numpy.tril_indices` nos bien muy bien:

```
arr = df.to_numpy()
tril_idxs = np.tril_indices(len(arr), k=-1)
tril_vals = arr[tril_idxs]
```

> ```
> >>> tril_idxs
> (array([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]), # Indice de las filas
>  array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])) # Indice de las columnas
>
> >>> tril_vals
> array([0.4 , 0.6 , 0.3 , 0.46, 0.69, 0.32, 0.57, 0.44, 0.41, 0.51, 0.41,
>        0.79, 0.33, 0.56, 0.43])
> ```

Ahora vamos a ordenar los valores pero nos interesan los índices de éstos para luego extrapolar al df original. Por ello vamos a usar `numpy.argsort`. Como no permite ordenar de forma descendente, invertimos la salida (`[::-1]`).

```
tril_idxs_sorted = tril_vals.argsort(axis=None)[::-1]
tril_vals_sorted = tril_vals[tril_idxs_sorted]
```

> ```
> >>> tril_vals_sorted
> array([0.79, 0.69, 0.6 , 0.57, 0.56, 0.51, 0.46, 0.44, 0.43, 0.41, 0.41,
>        0.4 , 0.33, 0.32, 0.3 ])
>
> >>> tril_idxs_sorted
> array([11,  4,  1,  6, 13,  9,  3,  7, 14, 10,  8,  0, 12,  5,  2])
> ```

Ahora ya tenemos los valores ordenados, solo nos queda extrapolar los índices de nuestro array aplanado al que tenian originalmente en el DataFrame, para ello, solo tenemos que ordenar tril_idxs de acuerdo a tril_idxs_sorted. realmente solo necesitamos los indices de las filas `tril_idxs[0]` para recuperar los indices del df.

```
res = pd.Series(tril_vals_sorted, index=df.index[tril_idxs[0][tril_idxs_sorted]])
```

> ```
> >>> res
>  
> idx
> Cmpd6    0.79
> Cmpd4    0.69
> Cmpd3    0.60
> Cmpd5    0.57
> Cmpd6    0.56
> Cmpd5    0.51
> Cmpd4    0.46
> Cmpd5    0.44
> Cmpd6    0.43
> Cmpd6    0.41
> Cmpd5    0.41
> Cmpd2    0.40
> Cmpd6    0.33
> Cmpd4    0.32
> Cmpd3    0.30
> dtype: float64
> ```

todo junto:

```
arr = df.to_numpy()
tril_idxs = np.tril_indices(len(arr), k=-1)
tril_vals = arr[tril_idxs]
tril_idxs_sorted = tril_vals.argsort(axis=None)[::-1]
tril_vals_sorted = tril_vals[tril_idxs_sorted]
res = pd.Series(tril_vals_sorted, index=df.index[tril_idxs[0][tril_idxs_sorted]])
```

Comment: Excelente solución, muchas gracias!